# Trying to handle iFrame but getting this error 'cypress-iframe commands can only be applied to exactly one iframe at a time. Instead found 2'

Tags: iframe, cypress

I am trying to automate react app and there are buttons that I need to click on which are on frames. Tried handling with cypress plugin for iframe and getting this error 'cypress-iframe commands can only be applied to exactly one frame at a time.  Instead found 2'.
This frame is under one more frame but doesn't know how to handle a frame within a frame.

Comment: Hi Oshin, Please post your code that you tired along with the screenshot of the error and also if possible the screenshot of your HTML DOM.